# Slick - Add null value to a field without using Option

Tags: slick

On Slick, is it possible to add null value without using Option?

I have tables with lots of columns, I don't want to define all fields as option field it will be painful to use by backend class.

The case class used by slick will be used in other layers, I could make duplicate class that mirrors case class used by slick and the classes used by other layer so that they don't need to use options. Is there any other better option?

Comment: `I don't want to define all fields as option field it will be painful to use by backend class`. But if the fields are null and you don't have `Option` how are you going to handle the null case? Option fields are there exactly to make you handle error cases.

Comment: I want the code in another layer to handle it.  It will handle null the same way Java can handle null. Let's say 2 modules are sharing the class, one module does not care about the most of the fields in the class while the other does.